# Image Processing using node modules and react in electron application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image-processing, electron, node-modules

I am trying to process an image at pixel level to remove the background of a portrait image. I am using React with electron. I did find few node modules which could help me with that, or else will write a module for myself. I was wondering how do I include the node module in react and use them to process images ? Is my understanding wrong ? Is there a better approach to the problem? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: It's possible that these packages are made for node.js, and not client-side code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking a node module from react component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173127/invoking-a-node-module-from-react-component)